# Omnifaces ViewScoped generates a POST call

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-tomee, omnifaces

My app is using Tomee 7.0.5, Java 8, MySql, JSF 2.2, Omnifaces 2.7. Primefaces 6.1, Prettyfaces 3.3.3. I tried to use Omnifaces' ViewScoped annotation together with @Named in my backing bean. It is required to use OWASP to validate requests. For some unknown reason a click on a link is converted to a POST request and since this link is used to navigate to another page there is no token yet in the request and so the validate request fails. Now, if I use javax.faces.view.ViewScoped instead everything is fine. I have 12 applications with the same pattern.
Each app has a template with a p:toolbar and links to navigate like:

```
<h:link outcome="pretty:search" value="Search" 
onclick="showSpinningIcon();return true;" />
```

No errors in Chrome console. what am I missing here?

Comment: Try it with "return false" in `onclick`

Comment: thanks Kolossus, I tried your suggestion but no luck, same problem, even I removed the onclick event and still an "invalid" request because it was again a POST method.

Comment: JSF 2.2 is an API, not an a real implementation and version, please post these too.  And how is PrimeFaces or tomee related to the problem? And why do you need the OWASP token? PF already has CSRF protection, please read https://www.beyondjava.net/jsf-viewstate-and-csrf-hacker-attacks

Comment: From the log file: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885)